# Can I boot, format and install Windows XP without a keyboard?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, keyboard, format

How can I bootup, format and drive and install XP without a keyboard? Is it possible?

Comment: It is POSSIBLE, but would require extensive preperation and another working Windows system

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to install Windows XP without keyboard (and even without mouse).

1. Create **unattended** installation disk and do it automatically.
   Here is [instruction](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314459) for creating unattended installation disks.
   Also you can use [nLite](http://nliteos.com) (it's very easy to use) or tools like it. Look [here](http://www.thetechmentor.com/posts/how-create-windows-xp-unattended-installation-cd/) for doing it using nLite.
2. There are many **repacks** which can format and install XP with "recommended" parameters.
   But if you don't want to use suspicous repacks, there are many ways to create your own
   (for example, using WAIK. But it's another theme).
3. You can clone your drive to image and restore it in another PCs using **Acronis Data Migration**,   **CloneZilla** and tools like them.
4. Try doing an online search, for example, search "auto install xp" or "unattended xp installation".

Comment: Could you please post some relevant links here instead of sending people off to search?

Comment: And I'd suggest keeping it to legitimate options rather than mystery torrents. nlite may be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is broken, Windows XP offers on screen keyboard. But then you need a mouse! :)

Comment: That won't get you past boot

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the BIOS should have been **already** configured for boot from CD as @Scandalist mentioned. Thank you sir

Comment: Your BIOS doesn't check for a keyboard on boot?

Comment: You still need a keyboard to get past the press any key to boot from DVD screen I think. A better solution is to prepare an answer file for unattended installation.

Answer (score -1):

This is like sitting in your car at the top of a hill wondering how far you can make it without an accelerator.

In all seriousness, if its by way of magic alone that you do not need to set your bios to boot from the installation media it may be possible. A keyboard is one of the requirements for installing any version of Windows so I can't imagine you'd make it too far. Maybe up to the point where you have to type in your product key. ):

Give it a go and God speed sir.

Comment: Not entirely true. You can create an unattended installer and even leave out the activation code IIRC.

Comment: @slhck BIOS doesn't check for a keyboard?

Comment: I assume he doesn't have a keyboard, let alone a working OS to create an unattended installation.

Comment: @Scandalist , Turn off gravity and you'll go far;)